# Unable to connect to wired DHCP connection via my PC?

Tags: connection, dhcp

Hi As I upgrade my pc to ubuntu 11.10 I can't connect to the wired connection ! It doesn't even find my Device MAC address !!What can I do ?

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1333687 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1333687 (1.3 MB)
```

the answer of etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


sudo lshw -class network

 *-network       
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:cff20000-cff20fff memory:cff00000-cff0ffff memory:cff10000-cff1ffff


 lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIB (ICH10) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G92 [GeForce 9600 GSO] (rev a2)
03:00.0 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB368 IDE controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 Memory controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. Device 2d00 (rev 01)


uname -a
Linux mahdiar-EP45-UD3L 3.0.0-15-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 17:23:00 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you give more information about your hardware?

Comment: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)

Comment: nobody can help ??

Comment: I add it to the main post .

Comment: I try my notebook and I have the same problem .

Comment: It solved in my notebook but I have it in my pc!! NO ANSWER ????

Comment: Plaease help me !!!

Comment: @mahdiar - please keep editing your question - that's great.  However, remember when editing, please add what you have tried and add the **new** results -  for example I see that you have editing your `sudo lshw -class network` results - but it still says that you are using the r8169 kernel module.  Which suggestion did you try.  Also - please tidy up your comments by deleting them so that the number of comments doesnt get too large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel incorrectly matches this NIC with the r8169 kernel module.  This is shown by the `lshw` trace where it shows that the NIC has been disabled.

According to [this article](http://www.rvdavid.net/how-to-get-gigabit-speeds-from-rtl81118168b-pci-express-gigabit-ethernet-controller-on-ubuntu-linux/), the NIC should be associated with the r8168 kernel module.  With the incorrect kernel module you will either get slow speeds or no connection what-so-ever.

[According to Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-3.0.0/+bug/839393) - this is also a recognised bug with Oneiric - however, it looks like it has been resolved for 12.04 since Precise uses a newer kernel (v3.2)

---

## hardware issues

First, let's rule out a NIC hardware failure - [NICs can go bad](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2010-December/388075.html) (the firmware/ROM) - an indication of this is the fact that the MAC address is recognised as `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`

If you last had a working NIC with Natty (or previous Ubuntu version) - then boot your PC with a LiveUSB/LiveCD.

Test your wired connection - rerun `sudo lshw -class network`.  Look for the MAC address.  Also look to see if it still says disabled.

If it still fails to connect via a live usb/cd with the version of ubuntu it last worked with then you have a strong indication of hardware failure.

---

## potential software solutions

Once you have ruled out hardware issues, then lets concentrate on possible software solutions.

For the solutions below you will still need a valid internet connection...

If you have a spare NIC card that is not of this model I would insert this into your PC and connect to the internet via a wired connection.  If you can connect via wireless - do so.  Otherwise, you may need to move your hard-drive into another computer to do the following and then transfer it back to your original PC.

**FIRST - BACKUP YOUR SYSTEM with a good backup tool such as Clonezilla**

**Suggested Fix 1**

According to the launchpad bug report, this is potentially fixed if you enable the proposed repository in software sources and install the package `linux-backports-modules-3.0.0`

**Suggested Fix 2**

You may be able to download the Precise kernel (v3.2) and install this.

From the [mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-rc4-oneiric/) area of launchpad:

Download the amd64 headers.deb,  headers_all.deb and the image_amd64.deb files

then install the kernel using the syntax:

```
sudo dpkg -i [package_name].deb
```

**Suggested Fix 3**

This is something you may be able to resolve by downloading the realtek driver and compiling it yourself.

Download the [Linux source](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) - at the time of writing this it is v8.028.00

Unpack the tarball :

```
tar vjxf r8168*.tar.bz2
```

Change to the directory:

```
cd r8168-8*
```

Compile:

```
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

You can check whether the driver is loaded by using following commands.

```
lsmod | grep r8168
ifconfig -a
```

If there is a device name, ethX, shown on the monitor, the linux
driver is loaded. Then, you can use the following command to activate
the ethX.

```
ifconfig ethX up
```

Finally, blacklist the r8169 driver add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
#blacklist r8169 driver
blacklist r8169
```

---

## Potential workarounds

A similar [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/562742) mentioning odd-MAC addresses for the r8169 kernel module on older kernels gave a couple of suggested workarounds.

**work around 1**

Once booted stop and start the kernel module:

```
sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

**work around 2**

Boot from your Natty live CD - run `ifconfig -a` and record the MAC address for eth0.

Boot into oneiric. Examine your udev persistent rules and map the correct MAC address to eth0

```
sudo cp /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

change the MAC address.  If in doubt - please add to your question the contents of your rules file.

Comment: Thanks . I think The third one is the safest one . I do the same as you describe but it doesn't work . ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fdff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x2000

Comment: when did you last have this working?  According to this (http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2010-December/388075.html) - an ethernet mac address of FF:FF;FF:FF;FF is a sign of hardware failure (the firmware in the NIC has gone bad.

Comment: ... also (remember to edit your question with all replies) - does the `sudo lshw -class network` still say "disabled" ? (please update the question with what it says now after doing suggestion3) - if it does then we still have a kernel/hardware issue. Try the backport module and rerun `sudo lshw -class network` again. Also - we need to confirm or deny the potential hardware issue - boot from a Natty Live CD (or whatever version it last worked) - does the wired connection start to work? If it doesnt I'm afraid the hardware failure is very likely.

Comment: no it isn't disabled anymore . I try 11.04 and it works properly . and found device MAC address too.

Comment: great news - no hardware issue.  Dont forget to edit your question with what you have tried.  Please try the second suggestion (the new v3.2 kernel) and let us know the results.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated it .  I'd like to try it but it is RC version and maybe it cause other problems ! Is there any stable version ?

Comment: ... remember do a backup! Also, if you have any issues, you can always boot into the older kernel by pressing SHIFT on boot.  Drop into the chat room and ping me with @fossfreedom if you want to talk this through.

Comment: ...whilst you are trying the suggestions, I've also added a couple of workarounds.  Please can you also test these.  thanks.

Answer (score -3):

```
HWaddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Really? Is this your real MAC Address or you are spoofing ??
Change your MAC Address from Broadcast address to something else(Spoof another address):

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo service networking restart
```

Place the new MAC Address instead of `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`

Comment: It can be a problem with the module as described on another answer here. The user does not refer to any spoofing attempt.

Comment: Please review your answer, research if needed but be accurate when placing your answer here. The question seems genuine.