# Strange screen after boot loader?

Tags: boot, screen

After the boot loader completes the screen goes to the following image !

[image]
My VGA : xfx geforce 9600 gso 1.5g

What should I do ?

I reinstalled 11.10 , 11.04 and 12.04 but I have my problem yet !
Another point is that I install ubuntu file system in another partition . Maybe Some Wrong config file is still in my home folder .

In my opinion it's not about driver problem because I have 11.10 with driver without any problem and I think this problem occurs when I try ubuntu 10.04 live CD !

I try ubuntu 12.04 final release too ! and the same problem occurred !

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information, but looks like a video driver problem at first glance. What's your video card model? What's the last thing you did before it started doing this? Also, is that a legit monitor or a TV going through HDMI?

Comment: my VGA : xfx geforce 9600 gso 1.5g . the last thing is trying ubuntu 10.04 live CD . It is a monitor . As you know I try the answer of this post too http://askubuntu.com/questions/67064/unable-to-connect-to-wired-dhcp-connection-via-my-pc .Thanks  for your helps bruno

Comment: When you boot the cd, hit the enter key when you see the little keyboard logo. Then hit F6, then [ESC] then add this to the end of the line on the bottom: vga=771

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please explain more ? What happens then ?

Comment: It's forcing a certain video mode. Theoretically, it should prevent any proprietary drivers getting loaded and use your basic VGA video instead. Basically like video safe-mode. Thus, rending the CD bootable hopefully.

Comment: I'm using installed version not live .

Comment: @mahdiar - please can you try booting with `nomodeset` as per my answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834) .... also it would be extremely helpful if you can edit your question with what you have tried from the comments above and the current answers because often stuff in comments gets overlooked.  Thanks.

Comment: Now I have ubuntu 12.04 without nvidia driver ! Should I install the driver ? I don't have critical problems untill I install it .

Comment: @mahdiar - that decision is yours and what you need the PC to do - if you are working fine and can watch videos etc with the default opensource drivers - I would say dont replace something that works.  If you want to try the nvidia drivers and are feeling nervous - drive image your computer first before installing the drivers.

Comment: How can I drive image my computer ? After that I'll install the driver .

Comment: I install the driver and the problem occurs !! I try your answer but it doesn't solve my problem .

Comment: no solution yet ?!!

Comment: I tried ubuntu 12.04 final release !! It isn't solved yet !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall ubuntu 12.04 but this time there is no need to install the nvidia driver . so nothing wrong happens .  Thanks for your helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try booting up using the "recovery mode" option. Then get the official drivers from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us (It's the GeForce 500 drivers)

Check out the comment to my answer here: [Upgrade of nvidia graphics adapter fails on Lucid Lynx, low resolution only, no driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105421/upgrade-of-nvidia-graphics-adapter-fails-on-lucid-lynx-low-resolution-only-no/105427#105427)

He points to a good page about how to get the drivers working

If you have to you can install the lynx text browser to navigate to those places. It's not fancy, but it gets the job done in a terminal.
If this doesn't work try making a new partition and install it on that partition. If that doesn't work download ubuntu 11.10 again and install it from that.

Comment: I'm using 11.10 . I reinstalled ubuntu and VGA driver . After I reboot  it restarts automatically after the loading .